# getting "interface list is not an interface" in a simple base class and interface in generic implementation in c#

Tags: c#, class, generics, interface

I get Type

> 'BaseServiceTypeRecord' in interface list is not an
> interface

and can't figure out why.

**Base class and interface**:

```
public interface IBaseServiceTypeRecord<TType> where TType : struct, IConvertible
{
    TType Type { get; }

    string Name { get; }
}

public abstract class BaseServiceTypeRecord<TType> : IBaseServiceTypeRecord<TType> where TType : struct, IConvertible
{
    private readonly TType _type;
    private readonly string _name;

    public BaseServiceTypeRecord(TType type, string name)
    {
        _type = type;
        _name = name;
    }

    public TType Type => _type;
    public string Name => _name;
}
```

**Implementation**:

```
public struct AssetsServiceTypesRecord : BaseServiceTypeRecord<ServicesTypes>, IBaseServiceTypeRecord<ServicesTypes>
{
    public AssetsServiceTypesRecord(ServicesTypes type, string name)
    {
    }
}
```

**ServicesTypes enum**:

```
public enum ServicesTypes
{
    Default,
    Database,
    Secure,
    Repo,
    HTTPS,
    Slugify,
    Sites,
    Blazor,
    Configuration,
    Cookie,
    QueryExpression,
    Helper
}
```

I just want to pass in an type of enum

Comment: I don't believe enums can be used as type constraints, what are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: @JSteward to be able to define which enum I'm passing to the object

Comment: But you'd be passing the whole enum type which doesn't make sense, this seems like an xy problem, what are you trying to really solve here?

Comment: @JSteward that the base class can contain any type of enum, and I defined which one it is in the base class/interface so the implemented classes know which enum is in play

Comment: Why are you (re)adding the interface declaration on your struct?

Comment: @WonkotheSane no specific reason, it's just how I like to code. but it doesn't make a difference if I remove it, it still reports an error about the class BaseServiceTypeRecord

Answer (score 2):

Changed type from struct to class and it worked as expected.

**Code**:

```
public abstract class AssetsServiceTypesRecord : BaseServiceTypeRecord<ServicesTypes>
{
    public AssetsServiceTypesRecord(ServicesTypes type, string name) : base(type, name)
    {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: That's because structs in C# does not support inheritance.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen yepp figured that one out